# Triple integral - switching limits around

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

[image]

I have been attempting this question for more than four hours now. Since I don't have the answer key for it, I try and check my answer using Symbolab by ensuring all three integrals give the same volume. However, I haven't managed to get the that to happen till now.

For part (a): $z$ should range from $x^2 \to 3-y$, $x$ should range from $-\sqrt{3-y} \to \sqrt{3-y}$, and $y$ should range from $0 \to 2$. Are these correct for this part?

Following the confirmation that my answer for part (a) is right:
For part (b): We can split it into two integrals:

$x$ should range from  $-\sqrt{z} \to \sqrt{z}$, $y$ should range from $0 \to 3-z$ and $z$ should range from $1 \to 3$.
$x$ should range from  $-\sqrt{z} \to \sqrt{z}$, $y$ should range from $0 \to 2$ and $z$ should range from $0 to 1$.
Is this also correct?

Comment: Only a little correction, $y$ varies from $0$ to $3$ as the intersection of the plane with the line $y=0$ is at $y=3$

Comment: @RafaBudría But the question says that there's the plane $y = 2$ to consider? Shouldn't we stop integrating at that point?

Comment: You are right. Your solution is ok.

Comment: @RafaBudría I updated the answer. Could you please also check that?

Comment: You might get some help by looking at [my YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exmZ4nuWGM4&index=63&t=0s&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) on changing order of integration. Definitely the middle third of this one, and perhaps the previous lecture, too.